# How to publish XML files from a NuGet package to an ASP.NET Core 2.1 application

Tags: asp.net-core, nuget-package, asp.net-core-2.1, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

I have an ASP.NET Core 2.1 application (say, `MyWebApiApp`) that references a NuGet package (say, `MyPackage`), which contains models used in a Web API.  These models are documented using XML comments, and the resulting XML file is published along with the NuGet package (in `lib\netstandard2.0\MyPackage.xml`).

I want to use the XML documentation in Swagger, so I add the following to my `SwaggerGenOptions` in Startup.cs:

```
c.IncludeXmlComments(Path.ChangeExtension(typeof(MyPackage.MyModel).Assembly.Location, ".xml"));
```

So far, so good.  When I run the application from Visual Studio 2017, it successfully locates the XML documentation file in the NuGet package cache and generates the Swagger documentation.

Now I want to publish the web site. When I publish the web site:

- The XML documentation file for application (`MyWebApiApp.xml`) is copied to the publish folder (I have included `<GenerateDocumentationFile>true</GenerateDocumentationFile>` in `MyWebApiApp.csproj`).
- But the XML documentation file from my NuGet package (`MyPackage.xml`) is not copied.

I've tried adding the incantation from [this blog post](https://snede.net/add-nuget-package-xml-documentation-to-swagger/) to `MyWebApiApp.csproj`, without success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution [here](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/1458#issuecomment-420456386).

The following incantation needs to be added to the pubxml file:

```
<Target Name="_ResolvePublishNuGetPackagePdbsAndXml"
      AfterTargets="RunResolvePublishAssemblies">
  <ItemGroup>
    <ResolvedFileToPublish
      Include="@(ResolvedAssembliesToPublish->'%(RootDir)%(Directory)%(Filename).pdb')"
      RelativePath="$([System.IO.Path]::ChangeExtension(%(ResolvedAssembliesToPublish.DestinationSubPath), '.pdb'))"
      DestinationSubPath="$([System.IO.Path]::ChangeExtension(%(ResolvedAssembliesToPublish.DestinationSubPath), '.pdb'))"
      Condition="'%(ResolvedAssembliesToPublish.PackageName)' != ''
                  and Exists('%(RootDir)%(Directory)%(Filename).pdb')" />
    <ResolvedFileToPublish
      Include="@(ResolvedAssembliesToPublish->'%(RootDir)%(Directory)%(Filename).xml')"
      RelativePath="$([System.IO.Path]::ChangeExtension(%(ResolvedAssembliesToPublish.DestinationSubPath), '.xml'))"
      DestinationSubPath="$([System.IO.Path]::ChangeExtension(%(ResolvedAssembliesToPublish.DestinationSubPath), '.xml'))"
      Condition="'%(ResolvedAssembliesToPublish.PackageName)' != ''
                  and Exists('%(RootDir)%(Directory)%(Filename).xml')" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Target>
```